# Смена ширины DataGridTextColumn, когда уменьшается количество символов в поле

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Есть wpf окно, а на нем DataGrid. Там есть колонка Name, которая может редактироваться и в соответствии меняется ее размер - она расширяется.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Меня же интересует обратный процес - что бы она сужалась, когда пользователь затирает какие-то символы. Вот как есть на текущий момент:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот как мне нужно чтобы было:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Задавала через Setter в стилях для самых ячеек колонки значение

```
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
```

и

```
<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
```

но это не помогло.
Так же пыталась ввести TextBlock для ячеек этой колонки - тоже безуспешно.
`Width = Auto;` - тоже не вариант.

Подскажите, пожалуйста как сделать так, чтобы ширина колонки менялась в зависимости от контента. Вот код XAML проекта:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="File" Binding="{Binding Path=File}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Язык разметки в WPF называется XAML, а не xml (хоть XAML и является подмножеством xml, но почему бы не писать правильно?). И, пожалуйста, относитесь к отвечающим с уважением, не нужно выплескивать в вопрос кучу никому не нужного не относящегося к вопросу кода, неужели так трудно удалить всё лишнее и показать только что, что относится непосредственно к вопросу? Вы просто заставляете читать весь этот код и искать там нужные части потенциального отвечающего, который вполне может пройти мимо вопроса не захотев это делать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<DataGrid CellEditEnding="OnCellEditEnding"/>

private void OnCellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Column.Width = 0;
    e.Column.Width = new DataGridLength(0, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto);
}
```

Но ширина колонки будет меняться только после завершения ввода. Чтобы менять ее по мере ввода, придется подписаться на что-то другое, например:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                    <EventSetter Event="TextChanged" Handler="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var column = ((DataGridCell)((TextBox)sender)?.Parent)?.Column;
    if (column == null) return;
    column.Width = 0;
    column.Width = new DataGridLength(0, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto);
}
```